# How to delete a text file in java?

Tags: java, delete-file, overwrite, file-rename

I want to overwrite to a text file using java by first create a new file and then delete the old one and finally rename the file I just created with the same name of my old file.
But my code does not work.

```
                File oldFile = new File("charList.txt");
                    File newFile = new File("new.txt");
                    oldFile.deleteOnExit();

                    if(oldFile.delete()){
                       newFile.renameTo(oldFile);
                    }
```

Comment: Did you mean `newFile.renameTo(oldFile);`?

Comment: @MattBall sorry about the typo

Answer (score 0):

On some platforms (e.g. Windows!), you cannot delete a file that the current program or another one has open.  I expect that is what is causing the delete step in your program to fail ... if that is what is actually happening.

As @Matt Ball's comment points out, it might be the rename that is failing ... because in the code you showed us, you are actually renaming "new.txt" to itself!

Finally, your `oldFile.deleteOnExit()` call is almost certainly incorrect:

- It won't affect the deletion of `oldFile` in the following code ... if that is your intent.
- If it does succeed, it will (I think!) delete the file that you carefully renamed to "charList.txt".  A `File` denotes a file pathname ... not a file handle.

Answer (score 0):

- With `deleteOnExit()` you are deleting the oldFile when the virtual machine terminates. I think this is not what you wanted, as you are calling `delete()` on the same file in the next command.
- Additionally you are renaming your newFile to newFile instead of oldFile. Try

  newFile.renameTo(oldFile)